# How to plot with a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use a for loop to plot several functions with Matplotlib in Python, a simplified version of my code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = ["r", "g", "b"]
x = np.arange(0, 3, 1)

for i in [3, 4, 6]:
    plt.plot(x, i + x, color=colors[i], linestyle='solid', linewidth = 3, 
         marker='o')
plt.show()
```

But I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`. I know is something to do with exceeding the i value, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm hoping to get a plot like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colors` has 3 elements, meaning the maximum value you can use to index that list is 2, but you're trying to index it with `[3, 4, 6]`. You could try something like:

```
for j, i in enumerate([3, 4, 6]):
    plt.plot(x, i + x, color=colors[j], linestyle='solid', linewidth = 3, marker='o')
```

in this case, you're indexing `colors` with `j`, which runs from `0` to `2` as you need.